# Задача на нахождение одинаковых элементов

Tags: c++

Добрый день, задача состоит в том, чтобы помочь найти ошибку в опкоде к задаче (Задача обычная с acmp, когда-то давно на паскале писал, но сейчас на С++ никак):

> Даны два неупорядоченных набора целых чисел (может быть, с повторениями). Выдать без повторений в порядке возрастания все те числа, которые встречаются в обоих наборах.
>
> Входные данные
>
> В первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записано через пробел два целых числа N и М (1 ≤ N, М ≤ 106) — количество элементов первого и второго наборов, соответственно. В следующих строках записано сначала N чисел первого набора, а затем M чисел второго набора. Числа разделены пробелами или символами конца строки. Каждое из этих чисел попадает в промежуток от 0 до 105.
>
> Выходные данные
>
> В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT нужно записать в возрастающем порядке без повторений все числа, которые входят как в первый, так и во второй набор. Числа разделять одним пробелом. Если таких чисел нет, то выходной файл должен оставаться пустым.

Опкод:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int M, N, i, j, f, g;
    int a[10], b[10];

    cin >> N >> M;
    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
    for (f = 0; f < N; f++) {
        cin >> a[f];
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
    for (g = 0; g < M; g++) {
        cin >> b[g];
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) ;
        {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                cout << b[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Использую 10 студию (работой с файлами ввода и вывода пренебрег, тк сдавать на acmp не планирую). Прошу подсказать, где ошибка!

Comment: Какая ошибка-то у Вас возникает? И в каком месте?

Comment: Не выводятся одинаковые эл-ты массивов, то есть на этом месте 
cout << "\n\n\n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) ;
        {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                cout << b[j];
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Я вот только не увидел проверку повторяемости совпадающих элементов.

Answer (score 3):

Все очень просто, до вывода одинаковых чисел ваша программа просто не доходит, так как у вас тело второго цикла for пустое (стоит ; за циклом)!
Вот так все работает:

```
void main()
{
    int M, N, i, j, f, g;

    int a[10], b[10];

    cin >> N;
    cin >> M;
    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
    for (f = 0; f < N; f++) {
        cin >> a[f];
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
    for (g = 0; g < M; g++) {
        cin >> b[g];
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                cout << b[j] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, плюсанул вам к рейтингу, думаю в процессе изучения ( когда привыкну к синтаксису) буду избегать таких глупых ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Можно всё сделать гораздо проще:

```
int main()
{
    const int maxValue=105;
    int elementCount[2];
    cin >> elementCount[0] >> elementCount[1];
    bool arrays[2][maxValue+1]={false};
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
        for(int i=0; i<NM[j]; i++)
        {
            int value;
            cin >> value;
            arrays[j][value]=true; //помечаем, что в этом наборе есть число value
        }
    //Выводим только те числа, которые повторяются в двух наборах
    for(int i=0; i<=maxValue; i++)
        if(arrays[0][i] && arrays[1][i]) cout << i;
}
```

Этим способом мы автоматически избавляемся от проблем с возможным повторением в одном и том же массиве.

Делал по условию задачи (только вводвывод на экран вместо файла), не разбирая твой код. Я не понял, почему у тебя массивы из 10 элементов, если их может быть 105 и почему ты выводишь `cout << "\n\n\n\n"`? По условию этого быть не должно.